# Using HTML buttons in PHP loops

Tags: php, html

I have a html table displayed using foreach loop in php. And I do even have buttons to be clicked in multiple rows. And the code goes like this:

```
<form method="post">
<table>
<tr> <th> Item </th> <th>Click to select</th></tr>
<?php 
     $query="select items from items_table";
     $result=$con->query($query);         //$con is connection variable already initialized
     $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     foreach ($row as $index)           //loop
     {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $index['items']; ?>  </td>
            <td><input type="button" value="select"> </td>     //button here
        </tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
</form>
```

Now how can I get to know which button was pressed?
I have read some web pages, which says we need to be using AJAX, and I'm a newbie with no knowledge of how it works.. Please help me out!

I tried to have button inside a loop and expected that the buttons works correctly directly. But it gives wrong output.

Comment: Use a `button` instead of `input type="button"` - then you can specify the submission value separately from the button text. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attributes

Comment: How can i do it.. Please help me out! @CBroe

Comment: You can search the internet yourself for *html button element* - CBroe even linked the documentation for button. What else do you need, just visit the link. There are examples on there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got what u want I'd say you should handle your button or input
Some ways available

```
 $index['items']
```

Is Not Correct where u used

1. ```
   <input value=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>
   ```
2. ```
   <input name=foo[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>] value=<?php echo $row['id'] ?> >
   ```
3. ```
   <input name='foo[]' value=<?php echo $row['id'] ?> >
   ```

Then handle them :

```
 <?php
  foreach($_REQUEST['foo'] as $name => 
  $value){
   echo $name ."posted and its value 
   is:". $value;
  }
 ?>
```

OR

```
 <?php
  echo 'value of foo[1] Is '.$_REQUEST['foo[1]'] ;
 ?>
```

You can use FOR EXAMPLE $row['name'] Or any field name u have in your table intead of $row['id'] that I gave